# Wiil docker update command stop the container?

Tags: docker

I want to update the resources of one container on the fly using

```
docker update --cpus 4 --memory 256M mycontainer
```

Does it restart the container or affect the execution in other ways?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/):

> The `docker update` command dynamically updates container configuration.

Which means that you can freely update any configuration you like. But:

> With the exception of the `--kernel-memory` option, you can specify these options on a running or a stopped container. On kernel version older than 4.6, you can only update `--kernel-memory` on a stopped container or on a running container with kernel memory initialized.

So, till you are not using `--kernel-memory` option, you can use `docker update` without been restarted or stopped (according to the docs).

Answering your concrete question, turns out it will not restart your container.